# how to disable a openssl engine?

Tags: encryption, openssl, centos, aes

I am trying to compare openssl aes encryption performance with and without Intel AES-NI engine.
I am using CentOS6.3 whose openssl has already implement the Intel AES-NI engine.
which means my test cases

(some commands like

```
./openssl speed -evp aes-128-cbc -multi 32
```

)

has already been accelerated by aesni engine.

I want to disable the aesni engine as to make a comparison of  the accelerated one,
but I don't know how to disable the aesni engine.

Could anyone please tell me how to disable the engine?
Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

<strike>You can disable AES-NI by unloading the aesni_intel kernel module:</strike> This only disables AES-NI use by the kernel, not by user processes.

```
rmmod aesni_intel
```

Comment: I was wrong about this solution. It only disables AES-NI use in the kernel, not for user processes.

Answer (score 3):

There is an environment variable you can set to turn off NI:

OPENSSL_ia32cap="~0x200000200000000"

More details here: https://mjanja.ch/2013/11/disabling-aes-ni-on-linux-openssl/